# JMeter + Jenkins - How to view Response Data/Assert Failed Results using Performance Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am integrating `JMeter` to `Jenkins` and displaying the result/report using the `Performance Plugin` and so far it is working fine when the the report shows the Info about if the request is successful or failed, how much time does it take, percentage of error...

I would like to display here more Info if the request is failed, such as Response Data, or in case if it is failed because of an assertion, it should display the message here. Saying in other words, these approaches should act same as View Results Tree Listener in `JMeter GUI` but I do not know how to attach it to the `Performance Plugin` in Jenkins.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve it? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it add to your plan a View Results Tree and:

- fill in file name property.
- Click on Configure and check everything except CSV Column Names
- Set Errors only

This way, when an error occurs, you'll have all details in this XML file which you can load in JMeter after test to analyze errors.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I do not know how to attach this xml file to the Performance Plugin in Jenkins to analyse the result, can you please give me some tipps here?